# What is ui-route?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, meanjs

I'm trying to develop with a complete mean stack (mean.js). I'm learning so maybe this question is a basic one. I spent so many days reading about different routing types in my frontend (angularjs). I found differences between ng-route and ui-router, the last one is a 3rd party module and has some clear advantages. I read in internet that if I use "ui-sref" I get a generated html for my state and an "href" tag. I understand this, but I searched a lot and I didn't find anything about "ui-route" what is used for?

I installed the official article example provided in meanjs http://meanjs.org/ and I have this that I cant understand.

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" data-ng-hide="authentication.user">
        <li ui-route="/signup" ng-class="{active: $uiRoute}">
            <a href="/#!/signup">Sign Up</a>
        </li>
        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
        <li ui-route="/signin" ng-class="{active: $uiRoute}">
            <a href="/#!/signin">Sign In</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

What is ui-route in combination with ng-class for? Is always necessary that

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are a subset of Angular-UI, which has libraries that provide functionality beyond core angular.  Both generate hrefs.

`ui-sref` is part of `ui-router`, a routing plugin

`ui-route` is part of `ui-utils`, a toolkit with a bunch of extra methods.  It also creates a boolean `$uiRoute` for each element that you can match against, making things like active tabs easier to code.  See http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/ for more documentation.

So if you're using `ui-router` and `ui-utils` in your project, you could use either approach.  Otherwise you can pick and choose as needed.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. if ui-sref and ui-route generates href? why is explicitly declared in that example?

Comment: Because when you use `ui-route` it also gives a boolean `$uiRoute` that you can match against.  Makes things like active tabs easier to code.  I'll update my answer to include this, but check out the docs at http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/

Comment: Thank you so much now everything is clearer in my mind